# Filter condition in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I'm trying to execute if the table has data or not. If there's data only that table will show the other will stay on no records found and vice versa. I feel like I'm wrong about my condition.

```
 render() {
    const { legal_records } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              {legal_records.size ? (
                <div
                  className="table-responsive"
                  style={{ overflowX: "hidden", maxHeight: 600 }}
                >
                  <LegalService 
                    data={legal_records} 
                    onSettle={this.onSettle} 
                  />
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="no-content text-center my-3">
                  <i className="material-icons">find_in_page</i>
                  <h6 className="text-muted">No Record Found</h6>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              {legal_records.size ? (
                <div
                  className="table-responsive"
                  style={{ overflowX: "hidden", maxHeight: 600 }}
                >
                  <LegalDivision
                    data={legal_records}
                    onSelectPay={this.onSelectPay}
                  />
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="no-content text-center my-3">
                  <i className="material-icons">find_in_page</i>
                  <h6 className="text-muted">No Record Found</h6>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `legal_records`. Is that array or object?

Answer (score 1):

If `legal_records` is an array, you need to access .length instead:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

change the condition to:

`legal_records.length > 0`

Comment: sorry but I tried the .length it doesn't work :((((

Comment: Can you confirm that legal_records is an array? we can't see it here. Also are you getting an error or is it just rendering No record found?

Comment: List {size: 0, _origin: 0, _capacity: 0, _level: 5, _root: undefined, …}size: 0__altered: false__hash: undefined__ownerID: undefined_capacity: 0_level: 5_origin: 0_root: undefined_tail: undefined__proto__: IndexedIterable "here" - here's the console.log from the legal_records

Comment: and i tried to console.log(legal_records.length) it was undefined but for .size it has a value

Comment: Looks like you are using some external library for storing lists, there also seems to be nothing in the list (size: 0). The logic you have seems fine then, you'll need to confirm that the List that is getting passed to you has the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that legal_records is an array:

`legal_records.size` should be `legal_records.length`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `legal_records` is an *object* you could do something like this:

```js
Object.entries(legal_records).length > 0
```

Which will determine whether or not an object has any items in it.
See the docs on `Object.entries(...)` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Though, without knowing the type of `legal_records` it's hard to give an appropriate answer.